# Using a click event to have a menu appear - but not working with new code with Knockout and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Previously I had this code that was working to spoof a click event in a knockout method.

```
self.addProductToCart = function(data) {
var $productNotification =  $(".product-notification");
ax.Cart.addCartItem({product_id:data.id, name:data.name, description:data.description});
$productNotification.slideDown(1000).fadeOut(200, function() { $('#cart-nav a.first').click();});};
```

Now they want to use css3 to animate so I took that the slideDown method out and replaced it with this and it's not working. I am probably missing something stupid here. Thank you

```
self.addProductToCart = function(data) {
 var $productNotification = $(".product-notification");
 ax.Cart.addCartItem({product_id:data.id, name:data.name, description:data.description});
 $('body').addClass("test");
 (function() { $('#cart-nav a.first').click();});};
```

Comment: I don't think that `.click()` is being executed in the second block - it's defined in an anonymous function (why?) and then just discarded, since the function is never ran.

Comment: You're not executing the self-executing anonymous function.
Also, there's no Knockout in this question.

Comment: ok that makes sense regarding the function, but can you offer a suggestion in the code itself? This is a knockout method, but it is not obvious from the code block. I just need to modify this to show the dropdown and with the addClass method. I tried a bunch of things that didn't work.

Comment: This isn't a "knockout method" because there is no such thing. At least not one you'd write - all the Knockout functions are _in_ Knockout - you've written a normal JavaScript function. If it doesn't work, it either isn't being called or it is and it does not produce the desired result. Option 1 would require you to find out _why_ it isn't - the Knockout binding might be failing or missing. Option 2, however, is nothing to do with Knockout. The easiest way to check is to just debug it - if you hit a debug point in the function, then it's called - proceed debugging as normal afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't ask the question for snark, I am just trying to work through a problem. Apologize if all my terminology is off.

Comment: So, if you are trying to work through a problem, what happened when you debugged this code? Besides, we have no clue how is this "not working" - is the thing not showing? Not hiding? The click event not dispatching? The class not being added? The class not doing what it should? What _should_ the class be doing? Is it needed? There is no way to replicate what is happening. No context to work with. The only things that can be said based on the information provided is `.click()` is not triggered. And if the function doesn't work - it's either broken or not called. We _can't_ know more than that.

Answer (score 0):

As [Roy J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392102/roy-j) stated in the comments, you have an anonymous function that is not executing. It doesn't even appear that the anonymous function is necessary. Try changing this line:

```
(function() { $('#cart-nav a.first').click();});};
```

To this:

```
$('#cart-nav a.first').click();
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually did that - the AF wasn't necessary, not sure why I did that in first place. I'm running into an issue that I am trying to debug, on some of the pages where it doesn't dispatch the click event properly.